# HTML 2 column layout always full height

Tags: html, css

[image]I am trying to make a two column layout in HTML so that both columns always fill the entire screen no matter how much content. I want the left column to dictate the height of the right column (map column). So if the left column grows to 2000 pixels tall then the map column should do grow to 2000 also. If the left column is only 10 pixels worth of content then the map column should never be less than the entire browswer window height.

I have spent 8 hours trying divs, webflow, etc... and no luck. You would think this would take two seconds. Throw in some divs and make the 100% and done.

Here is what I have which does NOT work?

```
I have this html

<div class="table">
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell1">
    <div class="inner"> <!-- start left side -->
        <strong>Transaction ID</strong>
        <p>Nov 11th, 2015 at  2:44 PM</p>
    </div> <!-- END start left side -->
  </div> <!-- end 1st column -->
  <div class="cell2">
    <div class="inner">
    <div id="map-canvas" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; transform: translateZ(0px); background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223);"></div>
  </div>
  </div> <!-- end 2nd column -->
</div> <!-- end row -->
```

With this CSS

```
    .table {
        display: table;
        border-spacing: 12px;
    }

    .row {
        display: table-row;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-top: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .cell1 {
        display: table-cell;
        width: 49%;
        margin-right: 1%;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        margin 12px;

    }

    .cell2 {
        display: table-cell;
        width: 49%;
        margin-right: 1%;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        margin 12px;

    }

    .inner {
        padding-left: 12px;
        padding-right: 12px;
    }
```

Here is with the changes @mathew suggested below. Not sure why the margin on the left is even there. I even use cell2 css class for both columns.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/msechrest/czew7gy4/) with your html and css minus the working map.

All i did was add `height: 100vh` to your `.cell1` class like so:

```
.cell1 {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 49%;
    height: 100vh;
    margin-right: 1%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin 12px;

}
```

This seems to give the effect you are looking for. If this is not the result you are trying to get please let me know. Play around with it and delete a bunch of text to see if you have 1 sentence in there it is still the full height of the browser.

EDIT*: If you want it to look like the picture you need to remove the `border-spacing` from the `.table` class and set the `body` to `margin: 0;` like this:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.table {
    display: table;
}
```

I have updated the Fiddle to reflect these changes.
Hope this helps!

Comment: With my map in it the left side page content or text starts about 50% down the left column leaving a 400px gap that is the same height as the map. And the map is still only 400px tall.

Comment: please put your map code in your question or create a jsfiddle with it working in there so I can see the issue you are experiencing.

Comment: the text drop you are experiencing is because of the table format you are using in your css. If you add `vertical-align: top` to your `.cell1` class this should resolve that issue.

Comment: Jesus that was simple. Never would have found that vertical-align.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you were on the right path. I simply modified your html by removing the .row div and adding the class .col to the .col1 and .col2 divs (so that you only have to style them once). In my testing, that seems to work. Try the CSS and HTML code below and see if it works for you as well.

```css
.table {display: table;}

.table .col {
 display: table-cell;
 width: 49%;
 margin-right: 1%;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 margin 12px;
}

.inner {
 padding-left: 12px;
 padding-right: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
 <div class="cell1 col">
  <div class="inner"> <!-- start left side -->
   <strong>Transaction ID</strong>
   <p>Nov 11th, 2015 at  2:44 PM</p>
  </div> <!-- END start left side -->
 </div> <!-- end 1st column -->
 
 <div class="cell2 col">
  <div class="inner">
   <div id="map-canvas" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; transform: translateZ(0px); background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223);"></div>
  </div> <!-- end inner -->
 </div> <!-- end 2nd column -->
</div> <!-- end table -->
```